# Updating temporal table history

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a problem updating rows in a temporal history table in MS SQL Server 2016.

From the documentation, the steps that should be needed are as follows:

1. Disable system versioning
2. Modify the history table
3. Enable system versioning again

I tried creating a procedure that does this, but got this error:

> Msg 13561, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>   Cannot update rows in a temporal history table 'db.dbo.FooHistory'.

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(
    id int primary key not null
    , title nvarchar(50) not null
    , startTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL
    , endTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL
    , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (startTime, endTime) )

ALTER TABLE Foo
SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.FooHistory));

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateFooHistory] AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Foo SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);      

    UPDATE dbo.FooHistory
    SET title = 'Foo';

    ALTER TABLE dbo.Foo SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (
      HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.FooHistory,
      DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON
    ));

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    RETURN 0
  END
GO
```

It seems like SQL Server is checking if a table is temporal at "compile time" rather than at runtime. Is this true? Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: You would have to use dynamic sql for the update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot delete rows from a temporal history table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746197/cannot-delete-rows-from-a-temporal-history-table)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the UPDATE statement to this, and it will let you create the procedure:

```
EXEC(N'UPDATE dbo.FooHistory SET title = ''Foo''');
```

Comment: This.. does not work.

Comment: Just tested it again and it still works on what I'm using (2019, RTM-CU18). Maybe it is also affected by database settings, not sure.

Comment: My local is 2022, and tested in Azure DB.. it didn't work there for me.

Answer (score 7):

With SQL Server 2019 it does not work any more (neither with exec nor with sp_executesql). You need to use a workaround.

In order to prevent any other user to change something while the versioning is off first start a serializable transaction:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; 
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
```

Temporarily disable SYSTEM_VERSIONING on the table:

```
ALTER TABLE Foo SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
```

Modify the history table:

```
UPDATE dbo.FooHistory SET title = 'Foo';
```

Re-enable the versioning:

```
ALTER TABLE Foo SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (  HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.FooHistory, DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON));
```

Commit the transaction:

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Dynamic sql does work for me on Azure Sql db

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Server 2022 (and Azure SQL), I see the error is being raised by the query parser *before* it even attempts to run the `SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF );` part.

...and as with other errors raised by the parser before it even runs any DDL, the trick is to add [a `GO` *batching instruction*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio-transact-sql) so that the parser stops reading ahead and will run with what it read up-to-that point and only run the rest of the stateements when the previous statements complete.

I also had my statements wrapped in a transaction too (though using `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` wasn't necessary):

Like so:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION ddlTxn1;

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTemporalTable SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF );

/* The `GO` separator below stops SQL Server from complaining about the UPDATE below before it runs the `SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF )` above: */

GO

UPDATE dbo.MyTemporalTable         SET Foo = 'bar';
UPDATE dbo.MyTemporalTable_History SET Foo = 'bar';

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTemporalTable SET (
    SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (
        HISTORY_TABLE          = dbo.MyTemporalTable_History,
        DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON
    )
);

COMMIT TRANSACTION ddlTxn1;
```

Further reading:

- [SQL Server: What are batching statements (i.e. using "GO") good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711326/sql-server-what-are-batching-statements-i-e-using-go-good-for)
- [What is the use of GO in SQL Server Management Studio & Transact SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio-transact-sql)
- [SQL Server Utilities Statements - GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go)